# Buiding a mySQL database schema with ACL for multiple resources

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

There will be three different tables for three different kind of resources.
There will be a user table with user id and user name.
User can have one of the three permissions - Read, update and delete.
What will be the efficeint way to implement it as a relational database schema.

User can have ACL on any of the resource and there will be a resource pool also which will contain multiple resources.

Comment: I'd consider using PostgreSQL 9.5, as it supports Row Security.

Comment: Thanks Neil, but the row security can be implemented for database users only and I don't think I can use it with a seperate user table in database.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use whatever logic you want in a POLICY. Why can't you use real database users?